# JasperReports - É possível trabalhar com datasource com método dinâmico (não-estático)?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Estou tentando gerar um relatório alimentado por um web service.

A ideia é que na hora que o usuário chamar o comando de geração do relatório ele (o comando) chame um método que trará Java Beans retornados de um web service.

Num relatório preliminar de teste vejo que isso é possível, e o método em questão pode ser dinâmico (isto é, não-estático) e receber parâmetros, o que é bom.

Porém durante a criação visual do JRXML na ferramenta Jaspersoft Studio eu vejo que a fim de testar a geração do relatório é necessário que a fonte de dados (datasource) criada na ferramenta chame um método de uma classe que precisa ser estático.

Essa exigência é realmente necessária? Ou existe uma forma de contornar? Ou basta eu me conformar em testar chamando um datasource com método estático e depois gerar o relatório via código chamando um método dinâmico que está tudo certo?

Comment: Cara, dá sim.. dá de contornar. Infelizmente não tenho mais acesso ao fonte que fazia exatamente isso e preciso pesquisar sobre o assunto, pois mexia com isso tem um bom tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim da sim, inclusive eu trabalho desta forma com o Jasper, porem utilizando JSON como comunicador.

Eu tenho uma API onde gera um JSON com os arrays e objetos, com isto o Jasper le o endereco da API e monta o jrxml; (utilizado apenas para montar o jrxml).

Posterior a isto eu realizado upload do jrxml para a api, quando o usuario chama o relatorio a API compila e retorna o PDF com os dados para ele.